# How to convert MODIS (Vegetation Continuous Fields - MOD44B) to (.img and hdr) in ENVI

Tags: coordinate-system, remote-sensing, import, envi

Please can anyone help me to convert MODIS (Vegetation Continuous Fields) to (.img and hdr) formats? In ENVI, anytime i try using the MODIS conversion toolkit, a dialog box appears telling me to define BAD range. I did input the following (0-100, 200 and 253) but none of them work.

I was successful when i opened it using the Generic format tool(HDF) but can not reproject it unto geographic coordinate system. Please I need an assistance.

Eric.